# SAN certs are not working in istio ingress gateway

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-gateway

I have deployed istio ingress gateway behind the ALB load balancer ingress, also attached the SAN cert using ACM ARN. When hitting the URL, I am getting a 502 bad gateway.

Istio Version: 1.11.3

Kubernetes version: 1.19

Please help to figure out the issue.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    annotations:
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: <acm-arn>
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /healthz/ready
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-port: "30021"
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS": 443}]'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-1, subnet-2
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    name: istio-ingress
    namespace: istio-system
spec:
    rules:
    - host: integration.x.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
            servicePort: 443
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
    - host: staging.x.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: istio-ingressgateway
            servicePort: 443
          path: /
          pathType: Prefix
```

````
  kind: Gateway
  metadata:
    annotations:
    labels:
      gateway: service-centre-gateway
    name: gateway
    namespace: monit
  spec:
    selector:
      istio: ingressgateway
    servers:
    - hosts:
      - '*'
      port:
        name: http-80
        number: 80
        protocol: HTTP
      tls:
        httpsRedirect: true
    - hosts:
      - '*'
      port:
        name: https-443
        number: 443
        protocol: HTTPS
      tls:
        credentialName: san-certs
        mode: SIMPLE```
````

Comment: Gateway is in monit, ingress is in istio-system namespace. Looks like your objects are in different namespaces. please try creating your resources in the same namespace.

Comment: Thanks, @RakeshGupta for your answer. This same setup is working in other environments having wildcard certs, but in staging env, we have temporarily used SAN certificates. 
Most of my virtual service and destination rules of the application are in different namespace than istio-system.

Comment: Ok, I think istio needs to be enabled in a namespace. Please check that it is enabled in monit namespace

Comment: When I changed to wildcard certs the same setup worked. Not sure if istio does not recognize SAN certs.